# How to handle sign out/in with Apollo client websocket and keep a working subscription?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, hasura

I have a [sample React/Apollo application on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-thunder-pkzel) that tries to handle sign out / sign in actions with a subscription (to a sample Hasura GraphQL server with JWT auth enabled). The workflow is illustrated in below screenshots (To reproduce, check logs and click sign out button; refresh preview if required).

[image: Edit boring-thunder-pkzel]

I tried to handle it by resetting the websocket connection each time it should either clear the subscription (sign out) or retry (sign in) (`wsLink.subscriptionClient.close(false, false)`). But the `errorLink` (Apollo middleware) is not called any more after signing out, so I don't know how to catch it cleanly to trigger a sign in / re-subscription. However, the component keeps receiving errors. The error is somewhere but the error link is not aware of that.

If the error can be caught by the error link, I can plug all the logic I want to reauthenticate and I'm happy.

There are actually 2 questions here:

- How can I ensure the error link continues to catch the errors after a sign out (here: websocket reset)?
- What's the best way to handle sign out/in with Apollo websocket, if not this approach? (Ideally, I would like to remain on the same SPA page, interrupt the subscription, clear local data, show a sign in dialog and once signed in, restore subscriptions and data.)

---

***Edit:** In the meanwhile, I tried with the RetryLink, and it seems to work: subscription attempts are caught, giving the opportunity to catch, authenticate and re-subscribe. But I'm not sure this is really a good approach to handle sign out/in. Recommendations on how to handle it are welcome. [Here is the updated sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/apollo-subscription-with-auth-2-32uk9).*

---

***Original attempt:***

#### *Initial rendering:*

[image]

#### *Rendering after clicking the sign out button and logs showing the steps:*

[image]

---

*Note: The graphql server is a sample hasura app hosted on Heroku with JWT authentication enabled. The client app has a JWT valid for many years.*

Comment: Were you able to fix it? Killing me for few days now. :(

Comment: Sorry for the lates response. The last time I used Hasura, I was still an approch very similar to my edit above with a connection reset. Not pretty, I think, but at least it works.